# Angular2 component view updated continuously

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection, components

I have an Angular 2 component that displays a list of Items, and that registers to a service that publishes events. The problem is that even if I don't do anything when I receive an event, Angular updates the view (or at least do something when, I guess, it shouldn't).

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OO6SarPYcMfjLLg7FuDz?p=preview).

As you can see in the console, the "getTitle()" method of my items is called each time my service publishes a message.

Even if I don't register to my service and if my component doesn't implement the MyServiceListener interface, getTitle is called each time the service gets a message. If I don't give the service to my component in its constructor, everything is fine. So, something seems wrong with my dependency injection, but what?

Here is the relevant code of the plunker:

My service and its listeners interface:

```
export interface MyServiceListener {

    onMessage(_message: any);
}

export class MyService {

    private m_listener: MyServiceListener;

    constructor() {

          window.setInterval(() => {

              if (this.m_listener !== undefined) {

                  this.m_listener.onMessage("Hi");
              }

          }, 500);
    }

    setListener(_listener: MyServiceListener) { this.m_listener = _listener; }
}
```

The Item class:

```
export class Item {

    m_title: string;

    constructor(_title: string) {

        this.m_title = _title;
    }

    getTitle(): string { console.log("getTitle"); return this.m_title; }
}
```

My component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template : `
      <div>
          <ul>
              <li *ng-for="#item of m_items">
                  {{item.getTitle()}}
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    `
})
export class App implements TestBugAngularServiceListener {

    private m_items: Array<Item> = new Array<Item>();

    constructor(_communicationService: MyService) {

        this.m_items.push(new Item("A"));
        this.m_items.push(new Item("B"));
        this.m_items.push(new Item("C"));

        _communicationService.setListener(this);
    }

    onMessage(_message: any) {

    }
}

bootstrap(App, [MyService]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both articles : [Change detection](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2)  and [Angular immutability](http://victorsavkin.com/post/133936129316/angular-immutability-and-encapsulation) explain a lot of thing about how Angular 2 detect changes of object, and how the tree of components in angular 2 is traversed to perform data binding...

In your sample, I think your component "my-app" can be considered to be "Immutable", so changing its "change detection strategy" to OnPush solve your problem.

You can write this :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template : `
      <div>
          <ul>
              <li *ng-for="#item of m_items">
                  {{item.getTitle()}}
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    `
})
```

And after adding the import to ChangeDetectionStrategy, databinding of "my-app" will not be computed after each browser event, but only when its input change, so never...